# Is it possible to detect that a log-off has been aborted on windows?

Tags: winapi, windows-vista, shutdown

I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically restart an application that has been **terminated** in the beginning of a shutdown that will be **canceled** later.
On Windows, if an application calls `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` on shutdown , it can know whether the user has *cancelled it* or *not*, by checking if the `ENDSESSION_CRITICAL` bit is set in the `lParam`.
In my case I **don't** want to **block** any shutdown .

Is this possible ? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Why the `c++` tag?

Comment: A bit kludgy, but you could use Task Scheduler to create a task with a specific time trigger of (say) 20 seconds in the future.

Comment: @abhishek_naik, I used C++ tag so as to not have solutions for C#, VB

Comment: @JonathanPotter, creating a task in Task Scheduler requires admin privileges, which I don't have, and don't want to ask for.

Comment: @perrahmaouy no, any user can schedule a task to run as themselves.

Comment: I don't know, because the last time I tried to create a task that will run the app on start up for the admin user, it fails unless I has admin privileges. 
I think I found a solution to my problem, it seems to work right know. It deserve  a test.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are shutting down your app in response to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` instead of `WM_ENDSESSION`. Or ignoring the `wParam` of `WM_ENDSESSION`. Also, the use of `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` has nothing to do with being able to check the `ENDSESSION_CRITICAL` bit (or any other bit) in `WM_ENDSESSION`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I thought that the `ENDSESSION_CRITICAL` bit is set to `lParam` when the user press **Force shut down** button; an action that is possible only when Windows terminate all the application that didn't call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a **solution** :

I created a hidden window using `CreateWindowEx` to handle the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` messages:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
        {
            //clean up ...

            ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hwnd, L"      ");
            // What ? You said you don't want to block the shutdown ?
            // Yes I do. It seems to work different with a hidden window.

            return 1;
        }
        case WM_ENDSESSION:
        {
            // GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN) return Nonzero if the current session is shutting down
            // This loop waits for the user to cancel the shutdown
            while(GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN) != 0)
               Sleep(100);
            // The user has cancelled the shutdown here
            // I can run the process again using CreateProcess or what ever...
            // Once this line is executed this instance will be terminated

        return 0;
        }
        default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

The `return` values are very important (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms700677(v=vs.85)#the-application-has-no-visible-top-level-windows-and-needs-more-than-30-seconds-to-handle-wm_endsession-and-perform-shutdown-processing)).
As I didn't expected, a process without a top level visible window, even if it calls `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` (with a hidden window handle), it will not be shown in the list of applications blocking the shutdown. And if there's no other application blocking the shutdown, Windows will only wait for a few seconds, and then shutdown.

For the loop, I took the idea from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/115682). I don't know if there's a better alternative.

That's it.

Please test it, and correct me if I'm wrong.
Thanks.

[EDIT]
Here's the program main for a ready test:

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

string getExePath()
{
    TCHAR wpath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName (NULL, wpath, MAX_PATH);
    size_t i;
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    wcstombs_s(&i, path, MAX_PATH, wpath, MAX_PATH);

    return path;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
        {
            // A shutdown has been initiated
            ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hwnd, L"      ");

            return 1;
        }
        case WM_ENDSESSION:
        {
            // GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN) return Nonzero if the current session is shutting down
            // This loop waits for the user to cancel the shutdown

            while(GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN) != 0)
               Sleep(100);            

            // The user has cancelled the shutdown here
            // I can run the process again

            WinExec(string("\"" + getExePath() + "\"").c_str(), SW_HIDE);

            TerminateProcess(OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId()), 0);

        return 0;
        }
        default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSEXA wc;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "TestShutDownAbortClass";
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if( RegisterClassExA(&wc) == 0 )
        return 1;

    hwnd = CreateWindowExA(0,"TestShutDownAbortClass", "", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
        return 1;

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessageA(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageA(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if the user does not cancel shutdown, or force a shutdown? Your `WM_ENDSESSION` will loop indefinitely because of your call to `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`, as the system will not terminate the app automatically because it is waiting for it to call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()` to signal terminate/shutdown is safe to continue, but you don't do that. "*Applications should call [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()] as they begin **an operation that cannot be interrupted**, such as burning a CD or DVD.*"

Comment: I tested it, even if I don't call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy`, Windows shuts down the computer **without forcing** it , because the I'm **not** calling `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` from a **top level visible window**. So Windows give it about 30 seconds I think or maybe less, and then it shuts down.